# R - Waiting for a list of promises to resolve

Tags: r, asynchronous, future

I am receiving some values in my R process and I want to compute them asynchronously. I am using promises and future package.
This is how my current code looks like:

```
arr = list()
i=0
while(i < 10)
{
   a = read messages from KAFKA topic
   arr[[i]] = future(DoSomething(a))
   i = i + 1
}
```

Now, arr contains a list of promises

How do I get value() of the promise that has resolved first (and so on)?
Something like promise.race in javascript.

Comment: May be this can be helpful for you: https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/overview.html

Comment: The terminology is a little confusing in R and you're looking for the 'future' package ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html ), not the 'promises' package.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just re-read your question and saw that you were asking about getting the first result, not just all results.  Below is the code for getting that. It's a while loop that waits for any result to be ready and then moves forward when there's a result ready.

There is also a function called `promise_race` in the `promises` package, but the issue with the promises package is that it can only output results.  You can't get the value produced back into a variable for further computations in the main thread.

```
require(future)
plan(multiprocess)

longRunningFunction <- function(value) {
  random1<- runif(min= 5 ,max = 30,n = 1)
  Sys.sleep(random1)
  return(value)
}

arr = list()

#changed starting number to 1 since R lists start at 1, not 0
i=1

#If the number of futures generated is more than the number of cores available, then the main thread will block until the first future completes and allows more futures to be started
while(i < 6)
{
  arr[[i]] = future(longRunningFunction(i))
  i = i + 1
}

while(all(!resolved(arr))){ }

raceresults_from_future<-lapply(arr[resolved(arr)], value)
print(paste("raceresults_from_future: ",raceresults_from_future) )
```